# Why is my model taking my skybox's texture?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been looking at this problem for days and I can't figure out why my model takes my skybox's texture. It has just been bugging me forever. Here is what it looks like.[This is what my model looks like after the skybox is loaded in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moC7D.png) [What my model looks like before my skybox is loaded into the scene.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMXJF.png)

core.cpp main loop

```
while (!m_Window.closed())
{
    m_Window.varUpdate();

    m_Window.Do_Movement();

    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
    m_Window.clear();


    m_ModelShader.enable();
    glm::mat4 model;
    model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.2f));
    //model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(5.0f));
    glm::mat4 view = m_Window.m_Camera.GetViewMatrix();
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(m_Window.m_Camera.Zoom, (float)m_Window.getWindowX() / (float)m_Window.getWindowY(), 0.1f, 100.0f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(m_ModelShader.m_ProgramID, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(m_ModelShader.m_ProgramID, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(m_ModelShader.m_ProgramID, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(m_ModelShader.m_ProgramID, "cameraPos"), m_Window.m_Camera.Position.x, m_Window.m_Camera.Position.y, m_Window.m_Camera.Position.z);
    m_Model.Draw(m_ModelShader);

    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    m_SkyboxShader.enable();
    glm::mat4 projectionS = glm::perspective(m_Window.m_Camera.Zoom, (float)m_Window.getWindowX() / (float)m_Window.getWindowY(), 0.1f, 100.0f);
    glm::mat4 viewS = m_Window.m_Camera.GetViewMatrix(); //This is usually set to glm::mat4(glm::mat3(m_Window.m_Camera.GetViewMatrix())); to center on the camera.
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(m_SkyboxShader.m_ProgramID, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projectionS));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(m_SkyboxShader.m_ProgramID, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(viewS));
    glBindVertexArray(sVAO);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(m_SkyboxShader.m_ProgramID, "skybox"), 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, skyboxTex);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);



    m_Window.update();
}
```

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't be calling `glGetUniformLocation` every frame, it's bad for performance. Cache the result.

Comment: Can you post the code of your model shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL is a state machine, i.e. it remembers everything you do and keeps using the very last configuration you set. When you draw your model (`m_Model.Draw`) OpenGL still has the skybox texture bound and active from the previous drawing iteration… and hence applies it. It's good practice to either

- clean up OpenGL state at the end of rendering a frame
- clean up OpenGL state at the beginning of rendering a frame
- clean up OpenGL state set for a particular drawing batch right after the batch

or

- set/unset all OpenGL state to what's required for the next drawing batch right before drawing that particular batch.

In your case I suggest you unbind the texture after drawing the skybox.

Comment: Oh My GOSH I forgot about unbinding. Noob mistake.